# Notification PushSharp Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, notifications, push, pushsharp

To do push notifications to my Android app I use PushSharp, it's very easy.There is also tools for IOS push and I want to send notifcations but I don't find anything in Java to implement push for IOS.

If someone have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use java- APNS library for sending push notifications to IOS devices.
Please find link https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns